# My css looks messed up in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Need to make some kind of 'scheme'. It was working fine in Google Chrome but I hear now that it needs to work in IE, IE only.

Is there some way to fix my CSS/HTML or do I need to make it again from scratch? 
I'm new at CSS/HTML and I've always used Chrome/Firefox in the past.

Here you can see what I have already, live code is here

https://jsfiddle.net/Azcrod/w7jqyb36/

My CSS partial code here:

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, #E98300);
/* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-radial-gradient(white, #E98300);
/* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(white, #E98300);
/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: radial-gradient(white, #E98300);
```

…and here is a printscreen of how it looks in IE:

[image]

Version is IE 11 but I'm hosting it on a intranet server, if that matters.

Comment: IE version is? Do you need support for lower IE versions, too? E.g. it looks fine in IE11...

Comment: Version is IE11 here aswell. I'm hosting it on an intranet server(?) if that matters

Comment: @Azcrod it happen because of ms filters

Comment: @Azcrod i was faced same issue , a month ago

Comment: @Azcrod i think it happen only on IE9 and below

Comment: @Azcrod have you tried filter:none !Important;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem myself. Maybe I explained it the wrong way but what I had to do was go to IE's Compatibility View Settings and disable it for intranet sites. That worked somehow.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem you can accept your answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of the CSS you are using, IE div border shape changes,background  gradients etc. they are CSS3, meaning you need IE9+ usually to see them formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Color issue in IE**

put  this line on all css  class

```
filter: none !important;
```

specially color used classes

Comment: "The property is marked invalid because it's not supported by the current schema"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on wich version of IE you are using (I use IE11 and it looks fine). You can check the supported browser versions here: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients

For older Versions you can use the following CSS, but there is no multi-stop nor can you tell em to use an specific angle:

```
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#0066A1', EndColorStr='#FFFFFF'); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#0066A1', EndColorStr='#FFFFFF')"; /* IE8*/
```

For IE 9 see P.JAYASRI's Answer.